# Bank manager giving out personal information and slandering

Tags: privacy

I took 401k paperwork to a local bank to have notarized for a cash out, the bank manager that notarized the paperwork has a son the same age as my daughter and in the same school district. The bank manager told her son we cashed out a 401k and insinuated to her son that we were broke and needed the money to survive. Of course her son is spreading the news around and gave my daughter a hard time about it saying Her family was poor. Is there any legal recourse I can take against the bank or the manager for damages and slander?

Comment: Keep in mind that a statement cannot be slander or libel if it is true.  If the only offending statement is that you withdrew cash from your retirement account, and you did actually do that, then slander is off the table. But the violation of your privacy and perhaps other wrongs would remain, and any additional statements that were untrue might constitute slander.

Comment: Instead of a lawyer, you might try to contact the bank managers manager. Not that they would admit that anything wrong happened, but there’s a good chance that the two will have an uncomfortable conversation. Tell your daughter the next time she sees the son she should tell everyone very loudly that your parent talked to his dads manager, and tell the kids to ask their parents if they would use a bank where the bank manager tattles to his son.

Answer (score 2):

You would need an attorney to attempt this.

Your attorney would likely want to start with clear evidence of damages. Has your daughter suffered more than just mild embarrassment? Have her grades suffered? Has she needed to see a school counselor or dropped out of sports, or other clear, tangible evidence that your family has been harmed by this gossip?

With that, your attorney would likely send a formal complaint and demand letter to the bank, detailing a specific complaint and requesting a specific remedy, such as an apology and retraction, damage$, and sanctions against the bank manager.

If the bank does not come up with a satisfactory reply, then it might become a lawsuit. But most banks have significant legal departments, and you might have a very difficult and expensive fight against that.

Just raising the issue with the Bank may very well get the manager reprimanded, demoted, or terminated. But that doesn't really get anything for your family, and could potentially even make your daughter's school life even worse.

Comment: Advising to get an attorney, definitely the right beginning. Document with dates, times and locations as well as what was said.